# Are Python variables global by default?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

Consider the following code in python:

```
a = 10
def fun():
    print(a)
fun()
```

This works fine in ipython notebook, the output is `10`.

Consider this code in c++:

```
#include <iostream>

void fun()  {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()  {
    int a = 10;
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling, the error is:

```
compare-fun.cpp: In function ‘void fun()’:
compare-fun.cpp:4:18: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

I am confused about the python code, why can it call `a` even if `a` is not defined in `fun`?

Comment: That C++ code is **not** equivalent to the Python code. The equivalent Python code would result in the equivalent error.

Comment: Because you allowed to use global variables, but you must explicit make them global to modify them.

Comment: Not hard to test this in Python, `'a' in globals()` will return `True`

Comment: declaring `a` in scope, i.e. above fun() and in the global scope would be equivalent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP assertion/assumption that the C++ code is equivalent to the Python code is incorrect.

Comment: this is not a good use of close-voting; the question can be rephrased to a useful version for future visitors. Namely "is this python and c++ code not equivalent in terms of variable scope and if so why not"

Comment: @martineau learn by analogy at least for me is a good learning method.

Comment: @Tasos: And if the OP does that, I (and any others) can retract our close votes. In other words I think it's a totally appropriate use of the privilege. buzhidao: It's nice you learn that way, but it doesn't make your question suitable for this site, IMO (obviously others have a different opinion).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent python code to your C++ code is actually the following:

```
def fun():
    print(a)

def main():
    a = 10
    fun()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This, when run, produces the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "test1.py", line 6, in main
    fun()
  File "test1.py", line 2, in fun
    print(a)
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

The equivalent C++ code to your Python code is this:

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 10;

void fun()  {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()  {
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

This, when run, outputs `10`.

Answer (score 4):

In python, **all objects are treated equally**.  You can argue that this is or is not a good design decision, but that's how it is (and likely how it always will be) so let's accept that as an axiom.

Lets look at some code that python *should* want to support:

```
def bar(val):
    return val + 6

def foo(a):
    return bar(a * 2)
```

We want `bar` to be useable within the function `foo`, but in order to allow that, we need to allow any other object defined at a higher level in the scope hierarchy to also be available since we want to treat all objects equally.

Also note that this is actually a *very* useful property of python as it allows doing interesting things with closures:

```
def add_constant(constant):
    def add(value):
        return value + constant
    return add

add_3 = add_constant(3)
assert add_3(6) == 9
```

---

Also note that the following *is* an error (and is more like the c++ code that you posted):

```
def func():
    print a

def main():
    a = 10
    func()  # NameError!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the reason that this doesn't work is because the scope of `func` doens't have access to the scope where `a` was defined (`main`) since `func`'s scope isn't a child of `main`'s scope.

Answer (score 1):

Those 2 codes are not equivalent.

In Python you are defining the variable in a global scope, in C++ not.
If you change your code in C++ to this, it should work in a similar way:

```
#include <iostream>
int a = 10;
void fun()  {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()  {
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

To understand more about the scope in Python check [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime).

> A variable which is defined in the main body of a file is called a
>   global variable. It will be visible throughout the file, and also
>   inside any file which imports that file. Global variables can have
>   unintended consequences because of their wide-ranging effects – that
>   is why we should almost never use them. Only objects which are
>   intended to be used globally, like functions and classes, should be
>   put in the global namespace.

The concept is very similar in [C++](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm)

> A scope is a region of the program and broadly speaking there are
>   three places, where variables can be declared −
>
> Inside a function or a block which is called local variables,
>
> In the definition of function parameters which is called formal
>   parameters.
>
> **Outside of all functions which is called global variables.**

Comment: If I define python code in` __main__`, maybe the compiler will give the same error? Can you add that part?

Answer (score 1):

In your Python example, you can *use*(not call) `a` inside the function `fun()` because `a` was defined in the global scope. This means `a` is accessible throughout your entire program.

But as Ignacio has already told you in the comments, you two examples are not equivalent. In your C++ example, `a` is **not** defined in the global scope, but in the scope of `main()`. This means that `void fun()` has no way of knowing where `a` is defined, thus, an error is thrown. Your C++ example would work fine if you defined `a` in the global scope:

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 10;

void fun()  {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()  {
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

That is why your C++ example threw an error, while your Python example did not. You defined `a` inside a scope `void fun()` knew nothing about. As others have already shown, creating the equivalent code in Python to your original C++ example would also raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a Python variable is determined by where it has been defined. If a variable has been defined outside of a function or class, it is global. Otherwise, it is local, unless declared `global`. More on this topic: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php

Comment: Outside of a function or class.

Answer (score 0):

a is a global variable, so you can use it in the procedure.